# Display Html page via url in Winforms in .Net6

Tags: c#, html, winforms, .net-6.0

I am trying to to display an HTML page in Winforms by using a url of the said page.

I have tried it in .Net Framework, it works using WebBrowser tool and gives the exact result needed but this tool is not available in .Net 6 and I have to make it in .Net 6.

I even tried to implement WPF control but even the ElementHost tool is not available in .Net 6.

Is there an alternative method way to display Html or use .Net Framework tools in .Net 6?

Sorry for the lack of code since Winforms is mostly drag and drop, I will add any required code if needed.

Comment: What about this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newest (at time of writing) in-app browser control by Microsoft is [WebView2](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/). It's based on the latest Edge browser.

[Here is a link to the Microsoft documentation on how to set it up for WinForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/winforms)

Comment: I have seen the name floating around but I need to make it in Winforms, and as I mentioned ElementHost is also not available in Winforms in . Net 6

Comment: @TusharAnand sorry, somehow when looking up the link winforms changed to wpf in my head. Updated the link

Comment: No problem, I browsed through the page and point 5 of Step 5 mentions "Select the C# Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) card." So are you sure it will work in .Net 6?

Comment: Yes, it works in .Net6+ without problems. Just pick a .Net 6 Template